# Does the color black use more memory than white?

Tags: memory, colors

Something I heard a few times from IT guys (none of which are programmers) is that the color black uses more memory than the color white, so users should set their desktops to white, not black.

To be honest it sounds silly to me and I can't wrap my head around why one color would use more memory than another. Every once in a while I google about this to see if anyone else is talking about it, but I wanted to hear from someone who knew more than I do on the subject.

I'm less curious if it's possible, because I think it's total BS, and more curious if anyone else has heard this.

-- Not an April fools joke.

Comment: Also, "Gullible" is not in the dictionary.

Comment: Not April fools, I'm dead serious I've heard people say this, and not on this day. Yes, these people are in charge of important hardware and data.

Comment: @Helpfulcom: "I've heard people say this".  We're not doubting that.  The fact remains that this makes very little sense.  It makes exactly as much sense as telling you that the word "gullible" is not in the dictionary.   You should ask the people who say it.  Not us.

Comment: @S.Lott I didn't say I believed it, I said it didn't make any sense to me, and I wanted to feel vindicated.

Comment: @Helpfulcom: "I didn't say I believed it".  Interestingly, you repeated it here, rather than ask the people who said it.  I don't know what that means, but you afforded it enough credibility to ask a 3rd party.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the off chance you're actually serious...

Colors are usually stored via their pixel values via their Red, Green, and Blue components ([RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB)), as that's how our displays work. (Print work is often handled by storing Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and blacK pixel values, in the [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) mode.)

Regardless of [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth), whether it is 15 bit, 16 bit, 24 bit, or 32-bit, it takes the same amount of memory to store black (0x000000 for 24-bit) as white (0xFFFFFF). Both can compress equally well, too. (Any *solid* color background can compress very well; limited-color backgrounds can compress well.)

My guess is your friends prefer black because it is easy on the eyes. (At least, that's why *I* prefer black backgrounds, black background colored terminals and text editors, etc.)

Comment: Exactly what I figured. Thanks. Unfortunately I was serious.

Comment: They were backing white as the least memory-hungry color.

Comment: @Marcel, heh, my brain must have completely blocked that, "who can possibly stand white?"

Comment: @Helpfulcorn, were they talking about _power_? [LCD Screens](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=fact-or-fiction-black-is) do take slightly more power to show black than white, because the backlight is on for both, but power must be applied to the liquid crystal to _block_ the backlight for black pixels.

Comment: No, in fact the first time I heard it I asked if that's what they meant, but they reiterated then and on later dates it's memory.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 images, both 1920x1080p, one solid white, the other solid black. Saved them both as a png with the same settings. The white one was 10kb, the black one was 8kb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).